# What do i need to do for gulp serve to work? On Windows 7 64 bit gulp serve raises error in module.js:549

Tags: spfx, gulp

So this below is the output from running gulp serve - what do I need to do to get it running?

```
M:\>gulp serve
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-build-web'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (M:\gulpfile.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Comment: Have you carefully followed articles [Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment) and [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) ?

Comment: Yes I have carefully followed it many times and yeoman will scaffold the project but gulp serve fails - I am on a corporate network behind a proxy but I have added the proxy and port using npm config - what on earth do I need to do? Following the official Msoft documentation for this just does not work which is amazingly disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

To make SPFx work with proxy, you should correctly setup proxy settings in nodejs. [This](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/) is a good and short article on how to do that. Basically you should set your proxy via below code:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

However even in that case, it might not work as expected. The most common reason is issues with certificates. What you can do, is to disable certificates check by nodejs. That's not very secure, but if you need it only for SPFx development, that's fine. Run in your console:

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Then install SPFx with yeoman from scratch and check if `gulp serve` works.

Comment: Ooh new information - thanks! I have never seen this mentioned: set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 - I did do the npm config so ofc will try set NODE...thanks!